# Is it possible to Train an Model with Nvidia ODTK with only one class?

Tags: object-detection, nvidia, custom-training

I'm trying to train a model that can detect rotated rects. I've found the Nvidia ODTK, but I find nothing to indicate if I can train it with only one class (category). The default number of categories is 80 and now I'm not sure if it will work well with only one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--classes` argument. See https://github.com/NVIDIA/retinanet-examples/blob/main/TRAINING.md#other-arguments